# Get python process ID for a flask web site and/or port number?

Tags: rhel, python, kill, nohup

I have some web applications that I wrote with python flask. I know which port I started each one on and each was started using nohup. Each one was started with something like `nohup python mywebapp.py &`

When I look at my processes with `ps`, I only see something like

```
36697 ?        60-21:36:16 python
 36971 ?        63-19:11:43 python
 37038 ?        65-06:57:22 python
 37312 ?        54-23:33:16 python
 37442 ?        54-09:14:57 python
 37716 ?        47-19:45:17 python
 68019 ?        00:29:24 python
146568 ?        00:20:57 python
146699 ?        00:17:08 python
150622 ?        00:32:20 python
```

If I need to stop one particular web application, how can I get from a port number back to a python process id so that I can `kill` the process?

Comment: where does the port number get specified when you start(ed) them?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Great question, that is specified within the python code, specifically with a call to start an app server with the flask library/framework.

Comment: So the parameter `mywebapp.py` is enough to determine the port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lsof` to find the process id associated with a known port number

`lsof -i :*port*`

Alternatively, you may wish to use `netstat` which can display all network connections, routing tables, interface statistics, masquerade connections, and multicast memberships.

Try `netstat -tulpn`

Comment: This sounds like its along the right track but this server does not have lsof and I cant use apt-get. Are there any other commands similar to this that you would recommend?

Comment: if you have `netstat` you may be able to find it using `netstat -tulpn`. You may have to grep the output for it to be useful.

Comment: That did it, thank you! I can see the ports and then it gives me the PID in the last column, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

One other way is to add it to the flask app itself.

```
from os import getpid
print("Creating PID file.")
fh=open("/var/run/yourAppNameWithPort.pid", "w")
fh.write(str(getpid()))
fh.close()
```

Comment: Is this something I would do before I startup the app or can I do it even while the app is running?

Comment: You'd add this to you app, it would happen on startup. I usually use argparse and pass in the pidfile name as an argument, but that is just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get the PID of the last background job:

```
$ FLASK_APP=myapp flask run &
[1] 10947

$ mypid=$!

$ echo $mypid
10947

$ kill $mypid
[1]  + terminated  FLASK_APP=myapp flask run
```